# AWS SQS FIFO queue behaviour with AWS Lambda reserved concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sqs-fifo

So I have 10 message groups in FIFO queue having 2 messages per group and I have also reserved lambda concurrency set to 5. (Lambda completes execution in 1 min and SQS visibility timeout set to 2 mins)

when all 20 messages are pushed to queue, SQS inflight messages gets set to 10 and then after the execution time, 5 messages gets processed successfully and other 5 moves to DLQ.

And then the next executions inflight messages gets set to 5 (as reserved lambda concurrency set to 5.) and processes as expected (This should be the expected behaviour right?)

Any particular reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that 5 messages are being sent to the Dead Letter Queue? It seems strange that the `ReceiveCount` would increment when Lambda cannot process the actual messages. If you increase the `ReceiveCount`, do the messages then behave correctly? Is there a particular reason why you have set it to a value of `1`?

Comment: yes. Also checked the 5 logs, each log is having only 3 messages details. At first I did not knew if it was really ReceiveCount but tested with ReceiveCount set to 2 and it did process all the messages. and theres some business logic in setting it to 1